# How can I compile anything succesfully with g++, modules enabled?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++20, c++-modules

I have the following file:

#### File *Testing2.cpp*

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string ss = "aaaa";
    ss += "aa";
    std::cout << ss << "\n";
}
```

When I compile it like this: `g++-11 -o Testing2 Testing2.cpp -std=c++20`, I get the desired output. When I compile it like this: `g++-11 -o Testing2 Testing2.cpp -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts`, I get a runtime segmentation fault error.

**Question 1**: Is this a bug in g++, or am I missing something?

I had several similar issues, one with `std::filesystem`, one with `std::map`.
The code will not work properly, even if modules are not actually used.

**Question 2**: The above code does not even use modules. Why does g++ compile it differently when the `-fmodules-ts` is enabled from when it is not enabled?

Comment: cannot reproduce with compiler explorer https://godbolt.org/z/7939dMsoW (test 11.1,11.2,11.3,modules)

Comment: Sounds like your installation of the compiler/standard library is messed up. Please explain what environment you are working in and how you installed the compiler. Try removing and re-installing it or a fresh environment.

Comment: updated link with all test https://godbolt.org/z/bvox75Yb6

Comment: Thank you for the comments guys! My installation is from the Ubuntu toolchain ppa, and honestly it seems to have no problems.

Comment: However, g++ puts precompiled modules into a directory called gcm.cache. Interestingly, when I remove this directory, the program works well even with ```-fmodules-ts``` enabled. So the question is: why would g++ use the precompiled modules even if I use an #include directive instead of import?

Another note: if I recompile the iostream and string modules, the program, again, runs without errors.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, g++ will use the precompiled standard library modules, if available (located in the gcm.cache folder) in both of these cases:
`#include <string>` and `import <string>;`.

My problem was solved by removing the string and iostream modules from the gcm.cache directory and recompiling them (I used the command `g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c -x c++-system-header string`).